Nifi fail to load cert from keystore
I am learning NiFi and trying to start NiFi with self signed certificates in my Organization. I have certificates including ca.pem, ca.key, nifi.pem, nifi.key. I created keystore, truststore and configed nifi.properties after this direction. However I encountered the following error while starting NiFi. I checked and repeated the above steps several times and can't find out cause.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid nifi.web.https configuration in nifi.properties
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.connector.FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.<init>(FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.configureConnectors(JettyServer.java:688)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.init(JettyServer.java:204)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.initialize(JettyServer.java:1002) 
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:164)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:83)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:332)
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.security.util.TlsException: Error loading keystore
    at org.apache.nifi.security.util.KeyStoreUtils.getKeyManagerFactoryFromKeyStore(KeyStoreUtils.java:234)
    at org.apache.nifi.security.util.KeyStoreUtils.loadKeyManagerFactory(KeyStoreUtils.java:267)
    at org.apache.nifi.security.util.KeyStoreUtils.loadKeyManagerFactory(KeyStoreUtils.java:246)
    at org.apache.nifi.security.util.SslContextFactory.getKeyManagers(SslContextFactory.java:145)
    at org.apache.nifi.security.util.SslContextFactory.createSslContext(SslContextFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.nifi.security.util.SslContextFactory.createSslContext(SslContextFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.connector.FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.<init>(FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.java:86)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:294)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:162)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:93)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1075)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:270)
    at org.apache.nifi.security.util.KeyStoreUtils.getKeyManagerFactoryFromKeyStore(KeyStoreUtils.java:229)
    ... 12 common frames omitted


sorry, problem doesn't come from NiFi but from cert building options used to generate cert using OpenSSL. Despite that now I yet don't know what the accurate reason is, however, I bypassed it after removing "-aes256" option from openssql command.
